# Не отображаются русские символы при парсинге сайта

Tags: python, парсер, requests, кириллица

Пробовал менять кодировки, такая тема только с переводом в html файл или считывания данных с сайта с помощью requests, что делать?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import io
headers={
    'accept': '*/*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.167 YaBrowser/22.7.3.822 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
}
url=('any')
req=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')
# with io.open('parsing.html','w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
#     file.write(req.text)
tovary=soup.find_all('li',class_="even")
for t in tovary:
    print(t.text)
```

Вывод:

```
ÐÐ°ÑÐ°Ð»Ð¾Ð³ ÑÐ¾Ð²Ð°ÑÐ¾Ð²
ÐÐ¾Ð½ÑÐ°ÐºÑÑ
ÐÑÐ·ÑÐ²Ñ
ÐÐ¯ÐÐÐÐ¯ ÐÐÐÐÐÐ¬
ÐÐÐ¡Ð¢ÐÐÐ«Ð
ÐÐÐÐÐÐ¬ ÐÐÐ¯ ÐÐ ÐÐ¥ÐÐÐÐ
ÐÐ¾Ð´ÑÐ»ÑÐ½Ð°Ñ ÑÐ¸ÑÑÐµÐ¼Ð° "ÐÑÐ»ÑÐ½"
ÐÐÐ¡Ð¢ÐÐÐ«Ð
ÐÐµÑÑÐºÐ°Ñ "ÐÐ»Ð°Ð¼ÑÑ"
ÐÐµÑÑÐºÐ°Ñ "ÐÐ°Ð½ÑÑÑÑÐµÐ½"
ÐÐµÑÑÐºÐ°Ñ "Ð¤Ð¾ÑÑÐ°Ð¶"
ÐÐµÑÑÐºÐ°Ñ "Ð­Ð½ÐµÑÐ´Ð¶Ð¸"
ÐÐÐÐÐÐ¬ ÐÐÐ¯ ÐÐÐ¢Ð¡ÐÐÐÐÐµÑÑÐºÐ¸Ðµ ÐºÑÐ¾Ð²Ð°ÑÐ¸ÐÐ°ÑÐ½Ð¸ÑÑÑÑ Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð´ÐµÑÐµÐ¹
ÐÐ°ÑÐ½Ð¸ÑÑÑÑ Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð´ÐµÑÐµÐ¹
ÐÐ¸Ð²Ð°Ð½Ñ Ð¿ÑÑÐ¼ÑÐµ
ÐÐ¾Ð¼Ð¾Ð´Ñ, ÑÑÐ¼Ð±Ñ Ð¢Ð
ÐÐ±ÐµÐ´ÐµÐ½Ð½ÑÐµ ÑÑÐ¾Ð»Ñ
ÐÑÐ¾Ð²Ð°ÑÐ¸
Ð¡Ð¿Ð°Ð»ÑÐ½Ñ  "ÐÐµÐ»Ð»Ð°"
Ð¡Ð¿Ð°Ð»ÑÐ½Ñ "ÐÐ¸ÐºÑÐ¾ÑÐ¸Ñ 2" ÑÐ²ÐµÑ Ð²ÐµÐ½Ð³Ðµ/Ð´ÑÐ± Ð¼Ð»ÐµÑÐ½ÑÐ¹
Ð¡ÑÐµÐ»Ð»Ð°Ð¶Ð¸ Ð¸ ÑÑÐ¾Ð¹ÐºÐ¸
Ð¨ÐºÐ°ÑÑ ÑÐ°ÑÐ¿Ð°ÑÐ½ÑÐµ
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/554562 может поможет?

Comment: BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте после выполнения запроса, перед тем, как вы его передадите в BeautifulSoup, перекодировать содержимое принудительно:

```
req.encoding = 'utf-8'
```

У меня была такая ошибка, когда на странице в одной ячейке было два текста, английский и русский. И тот, что на английском отображался нормально, а тот, что на русском, точно как у вас. Вот такая вот явная перекодировка мне помогла. Надеюсь, что поможет и вам.